# Make an element stretch full width in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

This is the schematic of the navbar for a web application I am developing:

[ Brand [button] [button] [----- input field -----] ----- empty space ----- [button] ]

My code (simplified) looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar navbar-static-top no-print">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a class="brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">
          <i class="icon-large icon-group"></i>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <i class="icon-large icon-list"></i>
        </a></li>
        <li id="search">
          <form class="navbar-search">
            <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" placeholder="Search">
          </form>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <i class="icon-large icon-plus"></i>
        </a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav pull-right">    
        <li><a href="#">
          <i class="icon-large icon-lemon"></i>
        </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the input field to cover up the empty space and reach all the way to the button on the right side of my navbar. How can I achieve this?

Comment: With `.span-` classes (if you’re using Bootstrap 2.x). Not pretty or elegant, I know. But then again, neither is a lot of Bootstrap’s mark-up.

Comment: It all depends on how your code is set up! Can you edit your question and include some code?

Comment: I edited the question to include some code.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this cannot be accomplished with just bootstrap's css. Bootstrap uses columns to place their content which is not as dynamic as what you need.

I'd recommend using absolute positioning to accomplish this.

```
.navbar-inner {
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-inner .input-xxlarge {
    position: absolute;
    left: (pixels from the left);
    right: (pixels from the right);
    width: auto;
}
```

Disclaimer: this input would need to be changed back to `position: relative; width: 100%;` when you get to mobile sized screen (might to fiddle with that one)